# Wrapping angular app with cordova problem with inappbrowser app after login rwditects to an url which opens in browser

Tags: angular, cordova, inappbrowser

I wrapped angular6 app with cordova, and everything works find, but after login, or registering,  app is redirected to an  url where is server, and opens in browser... I added `window.open = cordova.InappBrowser`. Open inside device ready, but it did not help, after login, page redirects to url, and browser is open.

Comment: Could you post the related code ?

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Well the app is hosted on server. When I wrapped it with cordova to be a mobile app, after login, app is opening the browser with hosted url...and behaves the same as You add url in a browser, not like a mobile app.

Comment: My general question is is there any posibility router. navigate to invoke inappbrowser and route to be opened in the app not in the browser with hosted url

Comment: I am facing same issue, did you find any workaround?

Comment: If the "login" is a page in the app (only you make the call to an API) that's should not happens.